# Problems hiding WPF StackPanel (not expander)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, stackpanel

I have a real trouble with WPF `StackPanel` - I need to make it animated not only for scrolling its content horizontaly (this is ok more or less), but also I must make it expand/collapse (animated) by pressing some button on the containing window.

I have tried a lot of animated expander controls (for example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AnimatingExpander.aspx) but they have overloaded with functionality (and some artifacts with contained controls) and not suitable for my task.

So the question is how to make SIMPLE horizontal oriented `StackPanel` to expand/collapse with animation by button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to start an animation on a `ToggleButton.Checked` or `.Unchecked` event:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel">...</StackPanel>

...

<ToggleButton Content="Click Me">
    <ToggleButton.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyStackPanel" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     To="0"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyStackPanel" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     To="200"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: this is only collapse(( You could add only one event on button press. so it may be the best idea to use check box or something like this.

Comment: You can use a `ToggleButton` instead of a `CheckBox` - I've updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: You click on the tick image on the left hand side of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding a storyboard and double animation for stackpanel's width. By clicking the button you can start the animation in code or by defining event triggers.

Comment: amm.. I am new in wpf animation( could yuo plaese provide some code?